# Is there a scrollableTabColumn similar to a scrollableTabRow in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am looking for a good way of handling tabs in a responsive design.

I am using this composable for phones, displaying tabs on top of the screen:

````
@Composable
@UiComposable
fun ScrollableTabRow(
    selectedTabIndex: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    edgePadding: Dp = TabRowDefaults.ScrollableTabRowPadding,
    indicator: @Composable @UiComposable
        (tabPositions: List<TabPosition>) -> Unit = @Composable { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex])
            )
        },
    divider: @Composable @UiComposable () -> Unit =
        @Composable {
            TabRowDefaults.Divider()
        },
    tabs: @Composable @UiComposable () -> Unit
)```

However, I would like to use a column with the same properties for tablet layout.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NavigationRail](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-rail/overview) with `Modifier.verticalScroll` for it to resemble ScrollableTab with items placed vertically.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun NavigationRailSample() {

    val list = List (10){
        "Item $it"
    }

    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    NavigationRail(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        header = { Text("Header") }
    ) {
        list.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
            NavigationRailItem(
                selected = selectedIndex == index,
                onClick = { selectedIndex = index },
                label = { Text(text) },
                icon = {

                    val imageVector = when (index) {
                        0 -> {
                            Icons.Default.Favorite
                        }
                        1 -> {
                            Icons.Default.Explore
                        }
                        else -> {
                            Icons.Default.Settings
                        }
                    }
                    Icon(imageVector, contentDescription = null)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a workaround, but will not share the same visual properties of the ScrollableTabRow

Comment: As you can in the link it's the suggested component for tables or mid sized devices to display headers/labels vertically

Comment: If the visual properties you mention is indicator below selected item or other items it's not that hard to implement but the component you ask doesn't exist. This is the official Component closest to vertical tab row and you can add scroll to it